# CSS :hover not working in pratice

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on a personal design project where I have 5 tiles with images in them and when you mouse over any of them they display alternate text. I have included my source code but my problem seems to be when I test this by hovering over the tile I added the W3 snippet to nothing happens. If I inspect the code however and add the hover attribute in the Chrome inspect tool it seems to work just fine. What am I missing here?

Here is my code [My Code](https://s3.amazonaws.com/fetchme-prototype/new/index.html)

```css
.bottom p {
 text-align: center;
}
.bottom {
 margin-top: 200px;
 width: 50%;
}
.top {
 width: 33.33333333333%;
 display: inline-block;
 
}
.tile {
 height: 200px;
 justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
   overflow: hidden;
   padding-left: 0px;
   padding-right: 0px;
   border-style: solid;
   border-width: 5px;
   border-color:  /*Navy Blue*/ #333333/* FetchMe Orange #FBAA1E*/; 
 text-align: center;
 box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px #000000;

 
}

.tile p {
 z-index: 4;
 font-size: 24px;
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 font-weight: bold;
 text-align: center;
 margin-left: 35%;
 margin-right: 35%;
 
}

.img1 {
 flex-shrink: 0;
   min-width: 100%;
   min-height: 100%
}

.top p {
 text-align: center;
}

.fetch-form {
   padding-top: 50px;
   padding-bottom: 50px;
   margin: 0 auto;
   position: absolute;
   z-index: 3;
   margin-left: 110px;
   margin-right: 110px;
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
}
.tiles {
 margin-left: 0px;
 margin-right: 0px;
 z-index: 2;
 position: absolute;
 top: 150px;
 left: 0px;
 color: white;
 display: inline-block;
 padding-top: 10px;
}
.inner {
 display: block;
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
 
}
.slider {
 z-index: -1;
 position: absolute;
 padding-right: 0;
 padding-left: 0;
 margin-right: 0;
 margin-left: 0;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 top: 0;
 height: 600px;
 min-width: 100%;
}
.item {
 height: 600px;
}
.container {
  position: relative;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #008CBA;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 0%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: .5s ease;
  z-index: 5;
}

.container:hover .overlay {
 width: 100%;
}

.text {
  white-space: nowrap; 
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.image {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-10 fetch-form">

            <form action="order" method="POST" role="form" id="address_form">
            <div class="col-xs-12 fetch-form">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-8 input">
                        <div class="input">
                            <i class="icon-prepend fa fa-home"></i>
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Street Address (optional)" id="address" name="address" class="form-control input-lg" autocomplete="off">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-2">
                        <input type="hidden" name="zip_code"><input type="hidden" value="true" name="set_temp_address">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block btn" type="submit">
                            <i class="fa fa-search"></i> Fetch Me Food!
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row well well-sm" style="display: none;">
                <div class="col-xs-4 text-center">
                    <div class="radio" >
                        <label><center><i class="fa fa-taxi fa-lg hidden-xs">&nbsp;</i></center>
                            <input type="radio" id="type_delivery" name="order_type" value="DELIVERY" checked="checked">
                            <span class="radiosearch">&nbsp;</span><span class="ordertype">Delivery</span>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-4 text-center border-left">
                    <div class="radio">
                        <label>
                            <center><i class="fa fa-cutlery fa-lg hidden-xs">&nbsp;</i></center>
                            <input type="radio" id="type_takeout" name="order_type" value="TAKEOUT">
                            <span class="radiosearch">&nbsp;</span>
                            <span class="ordertype"><nobr>Pick-up</nobr></span>
                            <nobr></nobr>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-4 text-center border-left" >
                    <div class="radio"><a href="/account/groups" style="color: #333333;">
                        <label>
                        <center><i class="fa fa-group fa-lg" style="margin-bottom: 6px;">&nbsp;</i></center>
                        <span class="ordertype"><span style="margin-top:9px;" class="visible-xs">Group »</span></span> <span
                            class="ordertype"><span class="hidden-xs">Group Order »</span></span> </label></a></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 tiles">
       <div class="inner">
        <div class="col-xs-3 top tile container">
         
         <p>Restarunts and Catering</p>
       <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/fetchme-prototype/images/fruits-grocery-bananas-market.jpg" class="img1 image" alt="">
       <div class="overlay">
        <div class="text">Hello World</div>
       </div>
      </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3 top tile">
           <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/fetchme-prototype/images/fruits-grocery-bananas-market.jpg" class="img1" alt="">
           <p>Our Deals</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3 top tile">
     <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/fetchme-prototype/images/fruits-grocery-bananas-market.jpg" class="img1" alt="">
           <p>Grocery Shopping</p>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
      <br>
      <div class="col-xs-12 tiles">
       <div class="inner">
          <div class="col-xs-6 bottom tile">
           <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/fetchme-prototype/images/fruits-grocery-bananas-market.jpg" alt="" class="img1" >
           <p>Tailgates</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6 bottom tile">
           <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/fetchme-prototype/images/fruits-grocery-bananas-market.jpg" alt="" class="img1">
           <p>Order Anything</p>
          </div>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="slider col-xs-12">
         <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                   <!-- Slide one -->
               <div class="item active">
                <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/fetchme-prototype/images/download.jpg" alt="">
               </div>
                  <!-- Slide two -->
               <div class="item">
                <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/fetchme-prototype/images/download.jpg" alt="">
               </div>
                  <!--Slide three -->
               <div class="item">
                <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/fetchme-prototype/images/download+(2).jpg" alt="">
               </div>
                  <!--Slide four -->
               <div class="item">
                <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/fetchme-prototype/images/download+(2).jpg" alt="">
               </div>
          </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: Please post code here, I can't even tell which element the hover is supposed to be on

Comment: You don't have a class called `overlay` anywhere, let alone as a descendant of `.container`

Comment: @TylerH overlay is there, it's just covered by some other element. So when you hover over the first tile and inspect, you land on some other element. Issues with how the page is laid out

Comment: look under <p>Restarunts and Catering</p>
excuse the typo

Comment: There are 2 instances of `col-xs-12 tiles` div elements, your second one is covering up the first one, fix that and you are good. You need position your second one with a different top value and remove the margin top for the tiles. the way you positioned these are causing the issue

Comment: Its happening for me. The first tile does have that functionality. On hovering, i get an overlay with Hello World message.

Comment: @athultuttu It works in the snippet insert but if you visit the link in the above post it shouldn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an issue with other tiles overlapping the containers (z-index issue). You can try something like this:

```
.tiles {
    pointer-events: none;
}
.container {
    pointer-events: auto;
}
```

Comment: This would be a quick fix. I would recommend you refactoring your code so the elements are not overlapping.

Comment: While this is correct in identifying the issue, I did not test the code that you send as I was able to fix the issue by adjusting the z-index values to put the bottom tiles below the top tiles.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you have used .tiles class for both .col-xs-12 items which are supposed to be 2 rows of pictures.

.tiles class has top, left properties defined and are position property as absolute. Since both rows of pictures have same top and left positions from .tiles, the second one overlaps the first.

This is why hover will never happen for .container normally. hover is always happening for the second row which is on top even though 1st row is visible below.